# How do I make a long identity sign?

Tags: symbols, hyphenation

The dash `$-$` may usually be prolonged by apposing one or two times in math environment to get longer dashes `$--$` and `$---$`.

How may I double or triple the length of the identity sign `=`?

Comment: For example, `\mathrel{{=}\mkern-4mu{=}\mkern-4mu{=}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an optional argument to state the factor you like (default 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\longeq@wd}
\newcommand{\longeq}[1][2]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\longeq@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\longeq@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth\longeq@wd{$\m@th#1=$}%
  \makebox[#2\longeq@wd][s]{%
    $\m@th#1\mspace{1mu}$%
    \ifdim#2pt<2pt
      $\m@th#1{=}\hss{=}$%
    \else
      $\m@th#1{=}\kern-0.5\longeq@wd\cleaders\longeqfill@{#1}\hfil\kern-0.5\longeq@wd{=}$%
    \fi
    $\m@th#1\mspace{1mu}$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\longeqfill@}[1]{\hbox{$\m@th#1\mspace{-3mu}{=}\mspace{-3mu}$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

$a==b$

$a\longeq b$

$a\longeq[1.25]b$

$a\longeq[1.5]b$

$a\longeq[1.75]b$

$a\longeq[3]b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the factor is less than 2, we just superimpose two equals signs with a negative space in between. Otherwise we fill the space with leaders (copies of `=` with some negative space on either side).

Don't use it with factors less than 1, of course.

Comment: That's nice. I like your factor and accept your answer as I forgot to accept the answer @Steven B Segletes gave. It is quite useful to find an appropriate length.

Answer (score 11):

Just kern together a number of unit symbols.  Remember to isolate the units in groups `{=}` to avoid special spacing, and to wrap the whole thing in a `\mathrel`, to reacquire proper math spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x\mathrel{{=}\mkern-4mu{=}\mkern-4mu{=}}y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

While horizontal stretching may be a reasonable alternative approach in limited cases, beware that the stretch will turn rounded endcaps into ellipses.

Comment: +1 Can I suggest a shorter version? (again `:-D`) `=\joinrel=\joinrel=` does almost the same (`\joinrel` uses `-3mu` so the result is somewhat longer).

Answer (score 3):

A few packages, such as `stix` and `stix2`, support `\eqeq` and `\eqeqeq`.  You could stretch an equals sign horizontally with a `\scalebox` or `fontspec`.    You might also try `\ndtstile` from `turnstile`.