# How may I negate long equality signs?

Tags: symbols, hyphenation

As an answer to [How do I make a long identity sign?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584708/how-do-i-make-a-long-identity-sign) @egreg offered the solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\longeq@wd}
\newcommand{\longeq}[1][2]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\longeq@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\longeq@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth\longeq@wd{$\m@th#1=$}%
  \makebox[#2\longeq@wd][s]{%
    $\m@th#1\mspace{1mu}$%
    \ifdim#2pt<2pt
      $\m@th#1{=}\hss{=}$%
    \else
      $\m@th#1{=}\kern-0.5\longeq@wd\cleaders\longeqfill@{#1}\hfil\kern-0.5\longeq@wd{=}$%
    \fi
    $\m@th#1\mspace{1mu}$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\longeqfill@}[1]{\hbox{$\m@th#1\mspace{-3mu}{=}\mspace{-3mu}$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

$a==b$

$a\longeq b$

$a\longeq[1.25]b$

$a\longeq[1.5]b$

$a\longeq[1.75]b$

$a\longeq[3]b$

\end{document}
```

How may I negate the long identity signs as with `$\neq$`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `centernot`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,centernot}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\longeq@wd}
\newcommand{\nlongeq}[1][2]{\centernot{\longeq[#1]}}
\newcommand{\longeq}[1][2]{\mathrel{\mathpalette\longeq@{#1}}}
\newcommand{\longeq@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth\longeq@wd{$\m@th#1=$}%
  \makebox[#2\longeq@wd][s]{%
    $\m@th#1\mspace{1mu}$%
    \ifdim#2pt<2pt
      $\m@th#1{=}\hss{=}$%
    \else
      $\m@th#1{=}\kern-0.5\longeq@wd\cleaders\longeqfill@{#1}\hfil\kern-0.5\longeq@wd{=}$%
    \fi
    $\m@th#1\mspace{1mu}$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\longeqfill@}[1]{\hbox{$\m@th#1\mspace{-3mu}{=}\mspace{-3mu}$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

$a==b$

$a\longeq b\nlongeq c$

$a\longeq[1.25]b\nlongeq[1.25] c$

$a\longeq[1.5]b\nlongeq[1.5] c$

$a\longeq[1.75]b\nlongeq[1.75] c$

$a\longeq[3]b\nlongeq[3] c$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Employing the alternate solution at the cited answer, if you end up using an odd number of `=` signs for the construction, just apply `\not` to the middle one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\longeq{\mathrel{{=}\mkern-4mu{=}\mkern-4mu{=}}}
\newcommand\nlongeq{\mathrel{{=}\mkern-4mu{\not=}\mkern-4mu{=}}}
\begin{document}
$x\longeq y \nlongeq z$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Werner, in a comment below, notes a simpler syntax of

```
\newcommand\longeq{=\joinrel=\joinrel=}
\newcommand\nlongeq{=\joinrel\not=\joinrel=}
```

However, the `\joinrel` (join relation) macro uses a `3mu` shift to achieve the overlay, whereas, my original definition chose the shift as `4mu`, making the overall length slightly shorter in my original case, by comparison.

If one finds it too wide, jack up the negativity of the `\mkern`.  Here it is, to -10mu (was -4mu above):

[image]

Comment: Oooo, `\joinrel`.

Comment: @Werner Yes, but `\joinrel` uses a `3mu` shift.  I chose `4mu`.  So there.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks. I would have preferred the medium length identities in the answer of egreg.

Comment: @Sapiens Change my value of `-4mu` to, for example, `-6mu` or some other more-negative value, and the overall length will shrink.